# MVC 5 refresh partial view with information from post

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Hello I have this puzzle and i would like to share and see if my solution is plausible and possibly get some help.
Basically I have a view called "Create".
[image]

Now i click "Escolher Ficheiro" *(means "Choose File")*, I choose the wanted file and click fill.

So far so good, my file reaches the POST method and its ok at this point.
You can see in the image below that I extract that number from the file and the button "Create" its shown.

**However** as you can see my "Choose File" input gets null "Nenhum fic..."*(means no file selected)*
This happens because I return the View Create and it refreshes my whole page.
[image]

The thing is that I need to go trhough a POST action on my Controller, so i can read that **Prop1**.

For obvious security reasons I cannot set a file by default, so I have tried to have some partial views and returning only that partial, but there is something im missing completly. Is there a way of refreshing the "bottom part of the view trhough ajax but going trhough the action on the controller at the same time?

***Here is my controller Action:***

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "XL2XMLProcID,SourceXLFiles,Prop1,Prop2,TargetXMLFile,State")] XL2XMLProc xL2XMLProc, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile, string submitButton)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (postedFile != null)                    
            {
                // fetch the date from the file
                var h = new XLHelper();

                var v = h.Fetch("nrContaACreditarRC", postedFile.FileName, @"C:\somefolder\somefolder\somefolder\ExcelSamples\");

                if (submitButton == "Create")
                {                        
                    TestZipAndUpload(v);
                }
                else
                {
                    // extract postedFile data to show

                    xL2XMLProc.Prop1 = v;
                    ViewBag.comingFromFill = true;
                    return View(ActionName.Create.ToString(), xL2XMLProc);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                // posted file is null, throw error.
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction(ActionName.Index.ToString());
        }
        return View(xL2XMLProc);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes there is, you probably need to do this on the document ready event in javascript and have some potential flag to indicate a javascript method to do an AJAX call when the view gets rendered after post. alternatively separate the bottom part out in another partial view and on click of a button, do the ajax call. But since you are doing a full postback anyway, why not have the bottom part render the information needed from the ViewModel?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i can have the partial view down below like:
`@Html.Partial("BlockChooseFile", Model)` However that doesnt matter because when i do that `return View(ActionName.Create.ToString(), xL2XMLProc);` the view is loaded again from scratch erasing the input field.

Comment: correct it would but you need to populate the property again on the POST action method when you are returning the View.

Comment: Sorry if it was a lack of communication but my problem is not the property, that is fine. The thing i want to maintain is the input type file. I think i will try some ajax call to controller on the partial itself.